# How to save a .ico image with certain dimensions using pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to save an image with x and y dimensions, I am using pillow to do so, the problem is that it is saving in default dimension, in my case 16x16, I tried using `resize` like this:

```
new_image = image.resize((40, 40))
```

but still the same result, the only difference is that in the preview of the image it gets smaller, but it stays 16x16, Does anyone have ideas?

```
image_byte = b"image_bytes"
b = base64.b64decode(image_byte)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
new_image = image.resize((40, 40))
new_image.save(icon_path)
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you save the image? It's very hard to guess what you are doing wrong if we don't know what you are doing

Comment: here, just added the code

Comment: Does this have something to do with Windows ICO files (which are containers for multiple formats)? Guessing based on `icon_path`... That would be an important detail here.

Comment: maybe, I am saving it in .ico, should I change it

Comment: couldn't hurt to try

Comment: Well, if you need something in .ICO format, then you'll have to save it as an .ICO. If something else will do just as well, then I'd use PNG.

Comment: you can post your answer if you want

Comment: Is there a particular reason you were using .ICO, @Flu_PyDeveloper? If you have some other software that expects ICOs, using a PNG won't work.

Comment: No particular reason

Comment: I just used it 'cause I wanted to try it

Comment: Wasn't my idea, thank @AKX :) a little tip for next time, give as many details as you think would be important to answer your question. You can try [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want to know more

Comment: ok I will, THX again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments:

When saving ICO files, you will need to [specify the sizes to save as](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2405#issuecomment-293374644) (since ICOs [can contain multiple sizes and formats of the same (or different!) image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#Icon_resource_structure)):

```
new_image.save('icon.ico', sizes=[(256, 256), (128, 128)])
```

If you don't need an ICO file, just use e.g. PNG (which contains a single format and size):

```
new_image.save('icon.png')
```